# Angular localized base URL

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm learning Angular v.5 + Express, and I want to translate application to 2 languages using Angular i18n tool. I want my url to contain the language I'm using as follows: `mysite.com/en/controller/...`

My idea is to use AOT compiler, according to [the guideline](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#merge-with-the-aot-compiler). Then, serve corresponding folder by Express. So, as a result I will have 2 built versions of my application, each in its own directory.

The problem is that I need to define base url in index.html file

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <base href="/en/">
  ...
</head>
```

And the URL depends on the current language. What I expected is that I can do something like

```
<base i18n href="/en/">
```

and then specify alternative path inside my translation file. However, this does not work. Am I doing something wrong? What is correct way to use i18n with AngularJS5 with such URL pattern?

Comment: Hello, just for you information, if you speak about v2+ you have to say Angular, olders versions are called AngularJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have to have the language in the url? If you removed it, you could just set your base url to `/`. In that case, your express server would detect the user's language and serve up the correct asset. So if `/controllers/myController.js` is requested, and the user's language is spanish, the server would return the file from `/es_ES/controllers/myController.js`.

PS: I believe the AOT compiler only works with angular 2+, so I'm assuming you're actually using Angular instead of AngularJS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No, I don't have to, but on my server side I know only one way to detect language - by matching URL. It would be nice if you can suggest the way to detect (and switch) the language without URL matching.

Comment: That's easy, check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845471/how-can-i-get-the-browser-language-in-node-js-express-js

Answer (score 3):

A nice solution could be to use ngx-translate (which is the same than angular-translate for angularJS.

Ngx-translate have a plugin for you need :

> Localize Router by @meeroslav: An implementation of routes localization for Angular. If you need localized urls (for example /fr/page and /en/page).

Ngx-translate link : https://github.com/ngx-translate/core

Here is the plugin link : https://github.com/Greentube/localize-router

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change base href in "index.html", you can define baseHref in "angular.json" build configuration, e.g. "baseHref": "/fr/".

Refer Angular I18N document https://angular.io/guide/i18n#build-for-multiple-locales