# Right way to add other languages to a website

Tags: node.js, express, web, mongoose

I am a newbie web developer, I am working with Mongo/Express/Node.

I am working on a website right now and was wondering what is the right way to add different languages? I worked with Android a bit and remember all string were stored into a String file and then depending on the language chosen by the user specific ones were chose. I imagine there is more than one way to do this, but I am not sure what is the best.

A few ways I can think doing it:

1. I can imagine hard-coding so that when the user clicks a language link it takes you to a website of that language with all new links, etc.  I have a feeling this is not the best though.
2. Not sure how but when  a language is chosen for a parameter to be added to all queries like ES or EN and then in the EJS page file have an if statement and depending on the param pick what to display. Not sure if it is right either
3. Storing diferent options in the database, not sure how this would work.

Anyways if someone could please tell me the right way to do this I would appreciate it, I want to learn how to do things the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right path, Node has a localization library:
https://github.com/AGROSICA/node-localize

If I were going this route, I'd probably store all dialog and user facing text in a JSON file and then return these based on the set localization.

You can also read the language header info set in someone's browser and programmatically make the call of which language to use: [How can I get the browser language in node.js (express.js)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845471/how-can-i-get-the-browser-language-in-node-js-express-js)